# Use cmd to get directory and convert to c++ string variable

Tags: c++, cmd

How do I get the folder that `efsd.txt`'s in's directory using `system()`; and set it to the string variable that I set below?

```
string textFileName = "efsd.txt";
ofstream textFile(textFileName.c_str());
string directory;
```

My full script is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string textFileName = "SavedPasswords.txt";
    string currentPassword = "Pas123!TTT54";
    string currentName = "Home";
    string seperator = "====================";

    ofstream textFile(textFileName.c_str());

    textFile << "N: " << currentName << endl << "P: " << currentPassword << endl << endl << seperator << endl << endl;

    string directory;

    string systemCommands[3] = {"cd\\",
    "cd " + directory,
    textFileName};

    system(systemCommands[0].c_str());
    system(systemCommands[1].c_str());
    system(systemCommands[2].c_str());
}
```

Comment: Instead of using the command line, which is a bit hackish. I would use a library called dirent.h works both in windows and linux, but in windows you have to include the source files. http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/code/dirent/dirent.html

Comment: Assuming I want to use the command line, how would I do this?

Comment: looking at your code, if the directory is always the directory of the exe, you can just use this, int main(int argc, char **argv)

then your argv[0] is the exe directory plus filename

Comment: Sorry, didn't work for me.  The file's a txt by the way, not exe.

Comment: @onlineone22 what saykou meant is if the TXT file is located in the same folder as the EXE, you can get the EXE's path from `argv[0]` and parse out the folder path from it. But why do you need to use `system()` as all? You do know that executing separate `cd` commands with separate `system()` calls won't work, don't you? What are you REALLY trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

"How do I get the folder that efsd.txt's in?" - there might be multiple files with that name, in different folders. In general, you don't want to go on a wild goose chase searching all folders; some of them may be big folders on a network and searching those can be quite slow. But I suspect you have an idea approximately where to look; you're just not telling us.

While working with files, using the Boost Filesystem library is an option for older compilers; newer compilers can use the standardized C++17 version thereof.